# How to make cross browser compatible list with list-style image properly?

Tags: css, xhtml

I need to make design like this,

[image]

to make this possible i used dotted line as background of li and + icon as a list-style-image. but it's not looking same in all browsers.

```
<ul>
   <li>item 1</li>
   <li>item 2</li>
   <li>item 3</li>
   <li>item 4</li>
   <li class="last">item 5</li>
</ul>
```

IE7 and 6 it's looking like this

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
li{list-style-image: url(/images/list.png);_list-style-image: url(/images/list2.png);}
```

where list1 it's the original with 12x12(px), list2 20x15(px) transparent and positioned at bottom left. Now i got the same view in all gekos and ie's. =)

You have to go testing the size of the second image, because the size varies according to many things.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting a `line-height` (or top and bottom padding values) on the LIs exclusively for IE6 and 7 to vertically center the [+] icon?
A css reset should fix the indentation - if it doesn't just use `text-indent` (or some margin-left or padding-left).

You can use `*+html li {}` to target IE7 and `* html li {}` for IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a **background image** rather than a **list-style-image**. The downside of this though is that the 2nd and any following lines of text will be padded as well.

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    background: url(path-to-image) no-repeat left center;
}
```

Comment: but the li has 2 background image. and i don't want to use css3 multiple background images

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: Oh okay, why aren't u using the border: **1px `dotted` #ccc** property instead?

Comment: because the same effect of dots also not compatible with cross browser compatibility.

Comment: well then just wrap the text into spans (and style it) this way you can use only one background image.

Answer (score -1):

You should edit the image so it is the height of one li, and it has (transparent) padding as part of the image. It seems to be impossible (or very hard) to control the position of the image cross-browser.